# How can I import a untrusted root certificate?

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, certificate, trusted-vs-untrusted

I am connected via VPN to some other network outside of my computer's Domain.  Everything works well except when I attempt to go to a WebSite within the VPN Tunnel (and in another domain).  This is the first message:

[image]

But the issue isn't that the certificate is invalid, it's that my system cannot validate the issuer...  most likely because my computer is not a part of the Domain through the VPN tunnel of which I'm accessing the web site.

[image]

So I was thinking, I just import this certificate and everything should work right?

The problem is I can't find this certificate anywhere on the system...  perhaps because it doesn't exist I don't know.  Does anyone know how to find this cert. as shown in the system above and import it?  Is there anything else I can do to allow this CA to install it automatically?

Comment: I tried a few things which didn't work (at code layer)...  I was able to see the certificate exchange, in particular the one that was sent.  I attempted to write the cert out and the thought was to then import it to certificate store.  The main problem was that there are many different cert types and I  didn't know specifically what type of cert. was sent in; as well as how to write it out using a specific cert type.  However, because the cert process requires the CA Authority, I'm pretty sure this wouldn't have worked being that it was only the public certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to get the certificate from the issuer, and just install it into the Certificate Store using the Operating System.  What I was trying to do above was to do it programmatically.  It didn't work because the key I was seeing was only the public key.